# How To Compare Table With Datatable or Datable A with Datatable B and update Table by c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want To Best and Fast Solution.

`Dt_AllPage` with 2 column and meny rows . `column 0 = ModelRam   and Column 1 = Price.` string.
`[dbo].[TBL_Sku_RAM]` with columns : `[ID]int,[SKU]string,[ModelRam]string,[Price]string`

I want to compare Each rows'column ModelRam Of `Dt_AllPage` with Each Rows' colmun Sku of `TBL_Sku_RAM` .

for this, select from `tbl_sku_ram` and append to `Dt_SelectTBlRAM` and compare two DataTable with names : `Dt_AllPage` with  `Dt_SelectTBlRAM`

and if Exist regex one rows of  `Dt_AllPage` in `Dt_SelectTBlRAM` then, get `ID` of `Dt_SelectTBlRAM` and get Price of this rowexist `Dt_AllPage` and update columns : [ModelRam],[Price] of `[dbo].[TBL_Sku_RAM]`;

**example:**

in `Dt_AllPage`

```
ModelRam                         Price
--------------                 ----------
4GB DDR3 PC3                      1,000
8GB DDR3 PC3L Geil 1.35V          5,000
```

in `[dbo].[TBL_Sku_RAM]`

```
 ID       Sku                     ModelRam                         Price
 --- -----------------          --------------                 ----------
  1 8GBDDR3 pc3L-1600               null                           null
  2  1GBDDR3-1066                   null                           null
  3  2GBDDR2-800                    null                           null
  4  1GBDDR2-667                    null                           null
```

**output:**

in `[dbo].[TBL_Sku_RAM]`

```
 ID       Sku                     ModelRam                         Price
 --- -----------------          --------------                 ----------
  1 8GBDDR3 pc3L-1600            8GB DDR3 PC3L Geil 1.35V          5,000
  2  1GBDDR3-1066                   null                           null
  3  2GBDDR2-800                    null                           null
  4  1GBDDR2-667                    null                           null
```

**code :**

**1)**

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Dt_AllPage.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       Model_name = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][0].ToString();

       DataSet Ds_SelectTBlRAM = DAL.SelectTBlRAM();
       DataTable Dt_SelectTBlRAM = Ds_SelectTBlRAM.Tables[0];

       for (int RowTBL = 0; RowTBL < Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows.Count; RowTBL++)
       {
           if (Regex.IsMatch(Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows[RowTBL][1].ToString(), Model_name))
           {
             
               int ModelId = (int)Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows[RowTBL][0];
               string Price = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][1].ToString();

               DAL.Update_Price_Model(Model_name, Price, ModelId);

           }


       }
   }
```

**2)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < .Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           Model_name = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    
           DataSet Ds_SelectTBlRAM = DAL.SelectTBlRAM();
           DataTable Dt_SelectTBlRAM = Ds_SelectTBlRAM.Tables[0];
    
    
           DataRow row1 = Dt_SelectTBlRAM.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("SKU").Contains(Model_name));
           foreach (DataRow row2 in Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows)
           {
               if (row1 != null)
               {
                   int Model_ID = (from DataRow DR in Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows
                                   where (string)DR["SKU"] == Model_name
                                   select (int)DR["ID"]).FirstOrDefault();
               }
    
           }
    
    
    
           string Price = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][1].ToString();
           Model_name = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    
       }
```

Comment: IF not clear , please request for comment for u and not close,please

Comment: Add the scheme for `Dt_SelectTBlRAM` and tell us what doesn't work with the current code

Comment: what is scheme? i dont know that how to add scheme for data table:((

Comment: just post it the same way you did with the other two tables. And what's wrong with what you did?

Comment: first way is true but not fast and professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Dt_AllPage.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           Model_name = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][0].ToString();

           DataSet Ds_SelectTBlRAM = DAL.SelectTBlRAM();
           DataTable Dt_SelectTBlRAM = Ds_SelectTBlRAM.Tables[0];


           DataRow row1 = Dt_SelectTBlRAM.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("SKU").Contains(Model_name));
           foreach (DataRow row2 in Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows)
           {
               if (row1 != null)
               {
                   int Model_ID = (from DataRow DR in Dt_SelectTBlRAM.Rows
                                   where (string)DR["SKU"] == Model_name
                                   select (int)DR["ID"]).FirstOrDefault();
               }

           }



           string Price = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][1].ToString();
           Model_name = Dt_AllPage.Rows[i][0].ToString();

       }
```